# Flask pagination example wont work missing "iter_pages"

Tags: python, pagination, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on a small web app to view some logfiles. But the
queries I issue to the database use to get very big.

I wanted to implement some pagination following this example [pagination](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/).
I put the class into a single file which gets loaded in the Flask view. Next I implemented
my pagination view like this:

```
@app.route('/index/', defaults={'page':1})
@app.route('/index/page/<int:page>')
def index(page):
    count = db_session.execute("select host,facility,level,msg from messages").rowcount
    tblqry = db_session.execute("select host,facility,level,msg from messages").fetchmany(size=1000)
    if not tblqry and page != 1:
        abort(404)
    pagination = Pagination(page, PER_PAGE, count)
    return render_template('index.html', pagination=pagination, tblqry=tblqry)
```

after that I created a macro file named `_pagination_helper.html` with the macro contents from the macro example. Then I imported the pagination_helper macro with:

```
{% from "_pagination_helper.html" import render_pagination %}
```

but when I then try to do something like this:

```
{{ render_pagination(host[0]) }}
```

flask claims:

```
UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'iter_pages'
```

so why does flask fails to find the 'iter_pages' because I included the pagination class in the views file?

And also I am not really sure where to put the URL Generation Helper from the How To.

***Edit***: 
This is what my pagination_helper looks like:

```
{% macro render_pagination(pagination) %}
  <div class=pagination>
  {% for page in pagination.iter_pages() %}
    {% if page %}
      {% if page != pagination.page %}
        <a href="{{ url_for_other_page(page) }}">{{ page }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <strong>{{ page }}</strong>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <span class=ellipsis>…</span>
    {% endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  {% if pagination.has_next %}
    <a href="{{ url_for_other_page(pagination.page + 1)}}">Next &raquo;</a>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: can you show us your `_pagination_helper.html` code?

Comment: @SyedHabibM: I guess it is identical to the one in the [referenced Flask snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/).

Comment: @SyedHabibM shure i can but Martijn Pieters is right it is the same as referenced in Flask snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expected to pass a `Pagination` object to the macro, not a string. `host[0]` is a string, not the `pagination` value you created in your view function.

Use:

```
{{ render_pagination(pagination) }}
```

Comment: this scripts is doing limit 1, 20 for first page (that is second page) and that is just wrong. what about zero limit 0,1 ?